# Why Xcode 3.2.6 can not pass correct parameters from active target to command line tools (compiler, etc)?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

When I change target options with Xcode (e.g. preprocessor defines, include paths, debug info format, pch usage) I still have the same command line. Why this may happen?

Couple of days ago it worked like a charm. I've just reinstalled it several times and now I think I will reinstall my mac?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "in any target in any project", or "in targets in one project", or "in one target in one project"? If either of the latter, then check your target settings and project settings in that project. Particularly, if you have any 'Other Compiler Flags' or similar, they might be overriding whatever Xcode is trying to achieve.

Failing that, I've known some people to recover from this sort of problem by creating a new project and importing all of their source files into that new project.

Comment: I know that stuff. After reinstall xcode again works as expected - paramters for command line are correct.